# Fetch anidados Promise {<pending>}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, funciones, fetch

tengo un problema:
estoy haciendo un contexto para mi estado global, en ReactJS
mis funciones devuelven datos, pero cuando trato de exportarlas desde un archivo externo tengo problemas con la promesa
Gracias, adjunto mi codigo:

en este fichero externo tengo la llamada a la API

```
const getPokemon = async() => {
    const url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=5";
    const result = await fetch(url);
    const response = await result.json();
    return response.results.map((pokemon) => getData(pokemon.url));
    //return response.results.forEach((pokemon) => getData(pokemon.url));
};
const getData = async(pokemon) => {
    //const url = pokemon;
    const result = await fetch(pokemon);
    const response = await result.json();
    return response;
};
export default getPokemon;
```

Estoy exportando esta funcion para agregarla a mi Context:

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import getPokemon from "../../services/getPokemon";

export const PokemonContext = createContext();

const PokemonProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => { 
        Promise.resolve(getPokemon()).then(resolve => 
            resolve.map(re => console.log(re)))
    }, []);
    const value = {
        pokemon,
    }
    return (
        <PokemonContext.Provider
            value={value}
        >
            {children}
        </PokemonContext.Provider>
    )
};

export default PokemonProvider
```

el console.log dentro de la funcion me devuelve lo que necesito, un arreglo de pokemon, pero al actualizar el estado me devuelve esto:

```
Promise {<pending>}
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Array(5)
```

cual puede ser mi problema?
Gracias

si me pudieras explicar porfavor como hacer lo mismo pero con un for

```
const getPokemon = async() => {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        //console.log(i);
        await getData(i);
    }
};

const getData = async(pokemon) => {
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemon}`;
    const result = await fetch(url);
    const response = await result.json();
    return response;
    //console.log(response);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que creas una promesa que se resuelve devolviendo un array de promesas, que hay que resolver:

```js
const getPokemon = async() => {
    const url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=5";
    const result = await fetch(url);
    const response = await result.json();
    return response.results.map((pokemon) => getData(pokemon.url));
    //return response.results.forEach((pokemon) => getData(pokemon.url));
};
const getData = async(pokemon) => {
    //const url = pokemon;
    const result = await fetch(pokemon);
    const response = await result.json();
    return response;
};

const pokemonListPromise = getPokemon();
console.log(pokemonListPromise.toString()); //es una promesa
pokemonListPromise.then(list => console.log(list.toString())); // es una lista de promesas
```

Una forma de solucionarlo es convirtiendo la lista de promesas a la promesa de una lista. Entonces pasaríamos de tener una promesa de una lista de promesas...

```
Promesa(lista(Promesa)) //representación de la anidación
```

... a una promesa de una promesa de listas, pero con la ventaja de que las promesas anidadas se "aplanan" solas, quedando

```
Promesa(lista)
```

que es mucho más sencillo de tratar:

```js
const getPokemon = async() => {
    const url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=5";
    const result = await fetch(url);
    const response = await result.json();
    const listOfPromises = response.results.map((pokemon) => getData(pokemon.url));
    //convertimos una lista de promesas en una promesa de una lista
    return Promise.all(listOfPromises);
    
};
const getData = async(pokemon) => {
    //const url = pokemon;
    const result = await fetch(pokemon);
    const response = await result.json();
    return response;
};

const pokemonListPromise = getPokemon();
console.log(pokemonListPromise.toString()); //es una promesa
pokemonListPromise.then(list => {
  console.log(list.length);
  list.forEach(pokemon => console.log(pokemon.name,":", pokemon.abilities.map(entry =>entry.ability.name)));
});
```

Comment: muchas gracias, por tu tiempo y la explicación

Comment: Está muy buna la solución pero como se haría para pasarlo a un Componente por ejemplo Pokemon.js donde tengo que mostrar la lista de pokemons